# Update (increment/decrement) leaderboard score in Google Play Games

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services, google-play-games

I used the following code to submit the user's score to Google Play Games:

```
if(getApiClient().isConnected()){
            Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(getApiClient(), getString(R.string.number_guesses_leaderboard),newScore);
}
```

but this doesn't **increment** the score of leaderboard, it just **replaces** the score. The same value is shown the all the time. `newScore` is the amount that I want to increment the current score by.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to save the current score locally using `SharedPreferences`, for example, and then submit the new **total** score to the Google Play Games service. Have a look a [this](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples/blob/master/BasicSamples/TypeANumber/src/main/java/com/google/example/games/tanc/MainActivity.java) sample by the Google Play Games team, specifically their use of an `AccomplishmentsOutbox` where they are storing the score locally until it is transmitted to the API.

Comment: This example is wrong, they dont refresh the leaderboard, its just local

Answer (score 3):

Here is a method I use to increment a google play services leaderboard.  If the score returned is null, score of 1 is posted.  Otherwise, current score is incremented by 1.  This is useful for keeping track of daily scores, for example.  Note the use of TIME_SPAN_DAILY to indicate the time span desired.  This will retrieve the highest score posted for the day, assuming "Higher is better" was indicated when setting up the leaderboard.

```
     private void incrementDailyLeaderboard(final LeaderboardsClient leaderboardsClient, final String leaderboardId) {

    leaderboardsClient.loadCurrentPlayerLeaderboardScore(
            leaderboardId,
            LeaderboardVariant.TIME_SPAN_DAILY,
            LeaderboardVariant.COLLECTION_PUBLIC
    ).addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<AnnotatedData<LeaderboardScore>>(){
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(AnnotatedData<LeaderboardScore> leaderboardScoreAnnotatedData) {
            //Log.v("onSuccess","onSuccess");
            if (leaderboardScoreAnnotatedData != null) {
                long score = 0;
                if (leaderboardScoreAnnotatedData.get() != null) {
                    score = leaderboardScoreAnnotatedData.get().getRawScore();
                    //Log.v("Your score is", Long.toString(score));
                }
                leaderboardsClient.submitScore(leaderboardId, ++score);
            }
        }
    });
}
```